# What is the value of $\int_C\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz?$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is analytic inside and on a simple closed contour $C$,and 
$z_0$ lies outside $C.$ What is the value of  $\int_C\dfrac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz?$

Comment: Zero, because $\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}$ is an analytic function inside and on $C$.

Answer (score 1):

$g:z\mapsto\dfrac{1}{z-z_0}$ is analytic on $\mathbb C-\{z_0\}.$

Since $z_0$ lies outside $C,g$ is analytic everywhere on and inside $C.$

Therefore $\dfrac{f(z)}{z-z_0}=(fg)(z)$ is analytic everywhere on and inside $C.$

So $\int_C\dfrac{f(z)}{z-z_0}=0$ due to the [Cauchy–Goursat theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem).